# $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally and $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, then will $\sum a_nb_n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally and $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, then will $\sum a_nb_n$ converge absolutely?

I know that $\sum|a_n|$ does not converge while $\sum a_n$  does
and that $\sum|b_n|$ does converge, and also that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_nb_n|=0$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4):

$|a_{n}|<1$ eventually and so $|a_{n}b_{n}|\leq|b_{n}|$ eventually, but $\displaystyle\sum|b_{n}|<\infty$, then so is $\displaystyle\sum|a_{n}b_{n}|<\infty$.

Comment: how when |$a_n$| diverges

Comment: I don't use that. Rather, if $\displaystyle\sum a_{n}$ exists, then its tail goes to zero.

Comment: ok but what so what if $\sum |a_nb_n| < \infty$

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: how does that fact show absolute convergence

Comment: Absolute convergence means that $\displaystyle\sum|u_{n}|$ exists as a real number, in other words, $\displaystyle\sum|u_{n}|<\infty$, because $\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_{k}|\right\}_{n}$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative real numbers, the supremum is either a real number or $\infty$.